# Add array's reference to dictionary

Tags: arrays, vba, dictionary

```
dim arr1 as variant, dict as scripting.dictionary

arr1 = array("cat")

dict.add "arr1", arr1

dict.item("arr1") = array("dog")
```

I want `arr1` now be pointing to `array("dog")`. After executing the code above, `arr1` is still `array("cat")`.
How do you assign items to dictionary by reference?

Comment: That's not even adding an array reference, that's adding a reference to a variable. VBA does not do that. You can only pass variables and arrays by reference to a method with `ByRef`, you cannot store the reference as a standalone entity.

Comment: Could you post a practical example where you might need this, so we could figure out how to handle this another way. Why the dictionary?

Comment: Your code example is poor.  The dictionary has not been initialised.  The code operates correctly.  Assigning dict.Item("arr1") as array("dog") will replace array("cat") in the dictionary, it will not change Arr1(0) from cat to dog.  Instead it changed dict.item("arr1")(0) from "cat" to "dog".

Comment: Arrays behave like value types, try using VBA Collection instead.